# Query Instagram posts by hashtag and time range

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to query posts from Instagram by providing the hashtag and the time range (since and until dates).
I use the [recent tags endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent).

> `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

My code is written in Node.js using the [`instagram-node`](https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node) library (see the inline comments):

```
// Require the config file
var config = require('../config.js');

// Require and intialize the instagram instance
var ig = require('instagram-node').instagram();

// Set the access token
ig.use({ access_token: config.instagram.access_token });

// We export this function for public use
// hashtag: the hashtag to search for
// minDate: the since date
// maxDate: the until date
// callback: the callback function (err, posts)
module.exports = function (hashtag, minDate, maxDate, callback) {

  // Create the posts array (will be concated with new posts from pagination responses)
  var posts = [];

  // Convert the date objects into timestamps (seconds)
  var sinceTime = Math.floor(minDate.getTime() / 1000);
  var untilTime = Math.floor(maxDate.getTime() / 1000);

  // Fetch the IG posts page by page
  ig.tag_media_recent(hashtag, { count: 50 }, function fetchPosts(err, medias, pagination, remaining, limit) {

    // Handle error
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    // Manually filter by time
    var filteredByTime = medias.filter(function (currentPost) {
      // Convert the created_time string into number (seconds timestamp)
      var createdTime = +currentPost.created_time;

      // Check if it's after since date and before until date
      return createdTime >= sinceTime && createdTime <= untilTime;
    });

    // Get the last post on this page
    var lastPost = medias[medias.length - 1] || {};

    // ...and its timestamp
    var lastPostTimeStamp = +(lastPost.created_time || -1);

    // ...and its timestamp date object
    var lastPostDate = new Date(lastPostTimeStamp * 1000);

    // Concat the new [filtered] posts to the big array
    posts = posts.concat(filteredByTime);

    // Show some output
    console.log('found ' + filteredByTime.length + ' new items total: ' + posts.length, lastPostDate);


    // Check if the last post is BEFORE until date and there are no new posts in the provided range
    if (filteredByTime.length === 0 && lastPostTimeStamp <= untilTime) {
      // ...if so, we can callback!
      return callback(null, posts);
    }

    // Navigate to the next page
    pagination.next(fetchPosts);
  });
};
```

This will start fetching the posts with the most recent to least recent ones, and manually filter the `created_time`.
This works, but it's very very inefficient because if we want, for example, to get the posts from one year ago, we have to iterate the pages until that time, and this will use a lot of requests (probably more than 5k / hour which is the rate limit).

Is there a better way to make this query? How to get the Instagram posts by providing the hashtag and the time range?

Comment: Could you just increase the `count` to grab a significantly higher amount of photos at a time to reduce the *amount* of post fetches? Of course they would be much larger but would something like this be beneficial?

Comment: @NickZ We did try to do that (I was debugging this is the OP) and the max we got was 33 items / request. So, the `count` doesn't really help... :-( Any other ideas? I'm happy to award 50 points to a someone who gives a good answer. :D

Comment: Have you looked into using MIN_TAG_ID and MAX_TAG_ID to iterate quickly towards a target date?

I can imagine a method which would query for only one post at a time to find a MAX_TAG_ID that is just before the date required.

Comment: Seeing that there isn't any parameter referenced, you'll need to do this filtering based on the response. Would it be unacceptable to grab the data and drop what you don't need?

Comment: @sbozzie Yes, that's probably what the `pagination.next` does internally. But that's not related to the date (or is it?). If you find a relation between date an tag id, that would be great (e.g. `21 March 2013` to be converted into tag id which being used will fetch the posts starting with that date). I guess the tag id is just an internal id, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MattWagner  That's what we're doing already: iterate the pages and get the posts that have created date in our interval... But that's expensive and slow.

Comment: To be clear: Are you trying to search through **all** instagram posts, or the posts for a specific user?

Comment: OP is using the tags/{tag-name}/media/recent endpoint. No user filtering as far as I can tell.

Comment: @FuriousFolder Like user5631389 said, we don't filter by users, just by tags and time (which is the limitation because we're getting the recent ones).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the basic idea you're looking for. I'm not overly familiar with Node.js, so this is all in plain javascript. You'll have to modify it to suit your needs and probably make a function out of it.

The idea is to convert an instagram id (1116307519311125603 in this example) to a date and visa versa to enable you to quickly grab a specific point in time rather then backtrack through all results until finding your desired timestamp. The portion of the id after the underscore '_' should be trimmed off as that refers, in some way, to the user IIRC. There are 4 functions in the example that I hope will help you out.

Happy hacking!

```
//static
var epoch_hour = 3600,
    epoch_day = 86400,
    epoch_month = 2592000,
    epoch_year = 31557600;

//you'll need to set this part up/integrate it with your code
var dataId = 1116307519311125603,
    range = 2 * epoch_hour,
    count = 1,
    tagName = 'cars',
    access = prompt('Enter access token:'),
    baseUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + 
              tagName + '/media/recent?access_token=' + access;

//date && id utilities
function idToEpoch(n){
  return Math.round((n / 1000000000000 + 11024476.5839159095) / 0.008388608);
}

function epochToId(n){
  return Math.round((n * 0.008388608 - 11024476.5839159095) * 1000000000000);
}

function newDateFromEpoch(n){
  var d = new Date(0);
  d.setUTCSeconds(n);
  return d;
}

function dateToEpoch(d){
  return (d.getTime()-d.getMilliseconds())/1000;
}

//start with your id and range; do the figuring
var epoch_time = idToEpoch(dataId),
    minumumId = epochToId(epoch_time),
    maximumId = epochToId(epoch_time + range),
    minDate = newDateFromEpoch(epoch_time),
    maxDate = newDateFromEpoch(epoch_time + range);

var newUrl = baseUrl + 
             '&count=' + count + 
             '&min_tag_id=' + minumumId + 
             '&max_tag_id=' + maximumId;


//used for testing
/*alert('Start: ' + minDate + ' (' + epoch_time + 
        ')\nEnd: ' + maxDate + ' (' + (epoch_time +
        range) + ')');
window.location = newUrl;*/
```

Comment: This looks awesome! I'm testing it right now––can you explain these magic numbers: `return Math.round((n * 0.008388608 - 11024476.5839159095) * 1000000000000);`?

Comment: A reference to where you found how Instagram encodes ids would be useful. This smells like undocumented functionality.

Comment: In all honesty, I made an instagram account today just for the sake of using their API console. Determining (approximating, actually) the encoding just took a little reverse engineering. It is not documented anywhere that I've found. :(

Comment: Found the documentation! http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

To be fair, it's a blog post, but it's still "official"

Comment: This officially doesn't work anymore unfortunately. Instagram started hashing their max_tag_id's and stopped support min_tag_id's

Comment: @KyleAsaff, would you provide a reference, please and thank you?

Answer (score 2):

To support [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187232/2014857) excellent answer, an instagram ID is generated via the plpgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insta5.next_id(OUT result bigint) AS $$
DECLARE
    our_epoch bigint := 1314220021721;
    seq_id bigint;
    now_millis bigint;
    shard_id int := 5;
BEGIN
    SELECT nextval('insta5.table_id_seq') %% 1024 INTO seq_id;

    SELECT FLOOR(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM clock_timestamp()) * 1000) INTO now_millis;
    result := (now_millis - our_epoch) << 23;
    result := result | (shard_id << 10);
    result := result | (seq_id);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

from [Instagram's blog](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram)

Answer (score 0):

Despite a similar getting posts process, Data365.co Instagram API, I currently working at, seems to be more suitable and efficient. It does not have a limit of 5,000 posts per hour, and you can specify the period of time for which your need posts in the request itself. Also, the billing will be taken into account only posts from the indicated period. You won't have to pay for data you don't need.

You can see below a task example to download posts by the hashtag bitcoins for the period from January 1, 2021, to January 10, 2021.

POST request: https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/tag/bitcoins/update?max_posts_count=1000&from_date=2021-01-01&to_date=2021-01-10&access_token=TOKEN

A GET request example to get the corresponding list of posts:
https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/tag/bitcoins/posts?from_date=2021-01-01&to_date=2021-01-10&max_page_size=100&order_by=date_desc&access_token=TOKEN

More detailed info view in API documentation at https://api.data365.co/v1.1/instagram/docs#tag/Instagram-hashtag-search